# Eloquent get rows depending on relationships' filters.

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I spent too much time investigating this problem. I have a table structure sth like this:

Table 1:

```
Shops
------
id
name
etc..
```

Table 2:

```
Days                 
-----
id
name
shop_id
etc...
```

Table 3:

```
Incomes
--------
id
day_id
etc...
```

I need to get the day objects, including the related income objects like this:

```
{
    id:1
    name:"2018-10-16"
    incomes:[ income objects... ]
}
```

I also need to filter these by table `days`' fields and also by table `incomes`' fields. So finally I only need those day objects with only those income objects where all the condition is okay.

I'm really confused, so sorry if it's not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have defined Eloquent Models for each table.

This is an abstract example.

```
$particular_days = Days::where([
    ['column_name', 'value'],
    ...,
    ...
])
->with([
    'incomes' => function ($incomeQuery) {
        $incomeQuery->where([
            ['column_name', 'value'],
            ...,
            ...
        ]);
    }
])
->get();
```

Comment: Guess it also works with ->paginate($someNumbe); at the end. Btw, I'll accept this answer in a few mins, many thanks!